# Expected value when there is a max limit on cumulative gain

Tags: probability, expected-value

You are playing a video game where you start at level 1 with 3 lives. The probability of winning a level is 90%. If you win, you gain a life and move to the next level. If you lose, you lose a life. The maximum number of lives that you can have at any given time is 3. The game finishes when you have zero lives left. What is the expected number of levels you reach ?

---

I realized that the game will end when the ending looks like LLL or LLWLL but I don't know if that helps to solve the problem in any meaningful way.

Comment: Saw [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1935507/how-many-games-required) but I don't think it's related to my question.

Comment: You have a Markov chain with four states, the number of lives you have left.  Write the equations relating the expected number of levels from each state.

Comment: @RossMillikan Understood